# Python Xpress get computation time and related statistics

Tags: python, mixed-integer-programming, xpress-optimizer

Xpress has some built in logging, including computation time, total memory available and threads used. However, there's quite a bit extraneous information in these logging statements. Is there a method to get this sort of information?

What I'm looking for

```py
xpress_problem.solve(get_time=True, get_memory=True)
```

These aren't real arguments that I've found from `solve` to be expecting, I just illustrate what I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is not queried by passing information to `solve()` but by querying solver attributes after `solve()` returns.

For example:
print(xpress_problem.attributes.time)

There are plenty of attributes, you can find all of then in the [online documentation](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/overview.html) in section [Xpress Solver Help > Optimizer Reference Manual > Problem Attributes](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/chapter8.html). Note that there attributes are listed as all-uppercase while in Python their names are all-lowercase.

These may be the attributes you are looking for:

- [time](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/TIME.html) - time spent solving the problem
- [peakmemory](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/PEAKMEMORY.html) - peak memory usage